# string arrange based on the character length in R

Tags: r, string

I have a data frame below as DT.

```
YEAR  STATE LEGAL         char
1998  24    L00161N11W2     11
1998  24    L00161N11W11    12
1998  24    L00163N9W6      10
1998  24    L00363N9W6      10
```

Can somebody suggest me an efficient way to split the LEGAL column and arrange as shown in the "output"? I have calculated the "char" column which shows the length of characters in LEGAL column string.

I need to establish a method to arrange the SEC, TOWN and RANGE columns based on the length of the characters.

```
Output:
    YEAR  STATE LEGAL         char   SEC  TOWN  RANGE
    1998  24    L00161N11W2     11   2    61N   11W
    1998  24    L00161N11W11    12   11   61N   11W
    1998  24    L00163N9W6      10   6    63N   9W
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "arrange the SEC, TOWN and RANGE columns based on the length of the characters"?  Do you need help creating those columns from LEGAL?  or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Yes, I need to create the SEC, TOWN and RANGE columns using the LEGAL column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `extract` from the `tidyr` package:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("YEAR  STATE LEGAL         char
1998  24    L00161N11W2     11
1998  24    L00161N11W11    12
1998  24    L00163N9W6      10") 

df %>% extract(LEGAL, c("TOWN", "RANGE", "SEC"), "L001(\\d+\\D)(\\d+\\D)(\\d+)", remove = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 7
#>    YEAR STATE        LEGAL  TOWN RANGE   SEC  char
#> * <int> <int>        <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1  1998    24  L00161N11W2   61N   11W     2    11
#> 2  1998    24 L00161N11W11   61N   11W    11    12
#> 3  1998    24   L00163N9W6   63N    9W     6    10
```

Comment: Looks correct but your TOWN column has extra 1 before 6. I want the TOWN output as shown in the "Output" table above.

Comment: I just noticed some rows has "L003". is there a way I can edit the above code to take into account any row that contains letter L?

Comment: @user3408139, you could change the start of the regex from `L001` to `L\\d{3}` so it is `"L\\d{3}(\\d+\\D)(\\d+\\D)(\\d+)"`.  This will match any entry which has an L followed by 3 numbers (e.g. L001, L003, L999 should all match)

Answer (score 2):

One base R solution to this would be to just use `gsub`.  In the code snippet below, I tried to use regex patterns which were maximally flexible.  For example, for extracting the `SEC` column, I used logic which says to match everything up until the last non digit character.  Then, capture and extract the digits which follow.  This solution should be relatively robust to your legal string.

```
df <- data.frame(YEAR=c(1998, 1998, 1998),
                 STATE=c(24, 24, 24),
                 LEGAL=c("L00161N11W2", "L00161N11W11", "L00163N9W6"),
                 char=c(11, 12, 10))

df$SEC   <- gsub(".*[^0-9]([0-9]+)", "\\1", df$LEGAL)
df$TOWN  <- gsub("L[0-9]{3}([0-9]+[^0-9]+).*", "\\1", df$LEGAL)
df$RANGE <- gsub(".*?([0-9]+[^0-9]+)[0-9]+$", "\\1", df$LEGAL)
df
```

**Output:**

```
  YEAR STATE        LEGAL char SEC TOWN RANGE
1 1998    24  L00161N11W2   11   2  61N   11W
2 1998    24 L00161N11W11   12  11  61N   11W
3 1998    24   L00163N9W6   10   6  63N    9W
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I can't for the life of me find it, but in the latest R isn't there a new function for extracting chunks from strings that match regex patterns?

Comment: Found it! https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.1/topics/strcapture `strcapture()`

Comment: @thelatemail But I don't want that solution because I don't want to use a single regex in this case, which could result in losing flexibility.  We don't have any documentation for the legal string, therefore we should not assume any structure unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Using `strcapture` in the most recent releases of R, which practically mirrors the `tidyr::extract` solution:

```
cbind(df, 
strcapture(
  "L\\d{3}(\\d+?\\D+?)(\\d+?\\D+?)(\\d+)", 
  as.character(df$LEGAL),
  proto=data.frame(TOWN=character(), RANGE=character(), SEC=character())
))

#  YEAR STATE        LEGAL char TOWN RANGE SEC
#1 1998    24  L00161N11W2   11  61N   11W   2
#2 1998    24 L00161N11W11   12  61N   11W  11
#3 1998    24   L00163N9W6   10  63N    9W   6
```